# MinGW fails to prefix _impl_ to exported functions

Tags: mingw, cross-compiling, dllexport

MinGW shall compile a shared C library `mylib` that contains functions like

```
declspec(dllexport) int foo();
```

The library shall be used in a C++ application under Visual Studio.

Building the library (under CMake, with option `GNUtoMS`) yields three files, `mylib.dll mylib.dll.a mylinb.lib`. To inspect the latter,

```
dumpbin /HEADERS mylib.lib
```

prints one stance per exported function. The stance for the above function `foo` contains the line

```
Symbol name  : _foo
```

So, MinGW does **not** generate the prefix `_imp_`. Expectedly, linking the dependent application fails because Visual Studio cannot find `_imp_foo`.

How to get this right?

Comment: You write "shared C library", which is "mylib.dll" in Windows. What is your "mylib.lib" then? How was it generated?

Comment: @jacob: I edited my question to answer your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Prefer the fork MinGW-w64 over the original MinGW**

Instead of

`mingw.exe` from http://MinGW.org,

use

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` from http://www.msys2.org.

With this, `dumpbin.exe` finds not

```
Symbol name  : _foo
```

but

```
Symbol name  : foo
```

and Visual Studio succeeds in linking `libmylib.lib`.

For background on mingw vs msys2/mingw-w64, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW): "In ... 2013 a new project was started, MSYS2 together with 32-bit and 64-bit MinGW packages. This project was created to keep track with newer advances of the Cygwin project ... MSYS2 is an independent rewrite of MSYS, based on modern Cygwin (POSIX compatibility layer) and MinGW-w64 with the aim of better interoperability with native Windows software."

MinGW [is a registered trademark](https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/lists/archive/users/2020-January/000447.html) licensed to the [MinGW project](http://mingw.org). The names of the compilers in the [MSYS2 project](https://www.msys2.org) are somewhat confusing: Occasionally they are called MinGW for short; the executables have `mingw32` in their name even when dedicated to 64 bits; the official name seems to be [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org).

Thanks to @jacob whose use of `MinGW-w64` in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59850241/1017348) provided the decisive cue.

Answer (score 2):

This is what works for me. I compiled this source code *main.c*

```c
__declspec(dllexport) int foo()
{
    return 42;
}
```

with this *CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(mylib)

add_library(mylib SHARED "main.c")
```

using this script *build.bat*

```
set "PATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;%PATH%"

cmake ^
    -G "MinGW Makefiles" ^
    -D CMAKE_GNUtoMS=ON ^
    -D CMAKE_GNUtoMS_VCVARS="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat" ^
    -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER="x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe" ^
    -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe" ^
    .

cmake --build .
```

As you can see, I used MinGW-w64 from MSYS2 rather than MinGW, but this should not make any difference. The output was:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/jacob/Documents/prog/stackoverflow/GNUtoMS

C:\Users\jacob\Documents\prog\stackoverflow\GNUtoMS>cmake --build .
Scanning dependencies of target mylib
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/main.c.obj
[100%] Linking C shared library libmylib.dll
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.4.3
** Copyright (c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 14.24.28315.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Creating library libmylib.lib and object libmylib.exp
[100%] Built target mylib
```

Then I created a program *prog.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllimport) int foo();

int main (void)
{
    printf("%d\n", foo());
    return 0;
}
```

and compiled it using

```
cl.exe prog.c libmylib.lib -o prog.exe
```

Linking succeeded, and the resulting program printed 42. The symbol displayed by *dumpbin.exe* was

```
  Symbol name  : foo
```

No underscores and imps whatsoever; still, it just worked.

Comment: Thank you, @jacob. The underscores and imps are not meant to appear in the sources; they are autogenerated, at least when compiling with VS. Could you possibly run `dumpbin libmylib.lib` and tell us whether you see `_foo` or `_imp_foo`?

Comment: @JoachimW It is written at the end of the answer. This is what the last sentence referred to.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your minimal example, and found the decisive difference to my environment is your use of `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` instead of `mingw.exe`. For clarity of the archival record, I posted this as a separate answer. Your help was essential for this.